# Got `invalid opcode` when deploying a contract to Ganache test network from Truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

I have launched Ganache 2.7.1 in Mac and using truffle `5.11.3`. I tried to deploy below contract to Ganache but filed:

**helloworld.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

contract Helloworld {
  
  function sayHello(string memory name) public pure returns (string memory) {
    return string.concat("Hello:", name);
  }
}
```

**below is the error I got:**

```
truffle(develop)> migrate

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.


Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'develop'
> Network id:      5777
> Block gas limit: 6721975 (0x6691b7)


1_deploy_contracts.js
=====================

   Replacing 'Helloworld'
   ----------------------
 *** Deployment Failed ***

"Helloworld" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
   * Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
   * Adding reason strings to your assert statements.


Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.
```

**The `truffle-config.js` file is:**

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
       develop: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "5777"
    }
  }
}
```

I have `1_deploy_contracts.js` saved in `migrations` folder:

```
const HelloWorld = artifacts.require("helloworld");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(HelloWorld);
};
```

The contract is very simple but I don't know what wrong with my projection.

The contract is very simple and I am not sure why it fails to deploy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because solidity 0.8.20 introduces the PUSH0(0x5f) opcode which is only supported on ETH mainnet and not on any other chains. That's why other chains can't find the PUSH0(0x5f) opcode and throw this error.

Consider using 0.8.19 for other chains.

Another way is to use a different EVM version like paris, london or berlin.

The way to change EVM version is `solc --evm-version <VERSION> contract.sol`

Although I think the prior solution is easy.

This should solve your problem.

If you want to learn more about PUSH0 opcode you can check this small article which explains it pretty well. https://www.zaryabs.com/push0-opcode/